# SSIS Package Script Component Won't Show

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, script-component

I have a strange bug, I have a loop in my control flow, amongst other things in the loop I have two data flow tasks, each of these has a script component in it. When I use the Edit Script button the new window opens but the Solution Explorer is blank and no script ever shows, nothing is frozen it just doesn't appear. There are other script components within this same package and within the other packages we use and the scripts for them all seem to open fine. I was having this issue initially with VS 2017. I had no luck fixing the issue so I uninstalled/reinstalled, but no luck. I downloaded 2019 and those two scripts still will not appear for me in it. I've had several co-workers open these and everyone else sees these scripts fine regardless of the VS version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74530949/2058808

Answer (score 1):

Because you reinstalled VS 2019 I guess that you downloaded the newest version (16.9) of Visual Studio.
Version 16.9 have a big problem with `script component` and everybody trying to fix this bug.
Unfortunately, you can only **downgrade** VS to version 16.8 or wait for 16.10.
On link below, you can read that "issue has been fixed in 16.10 which will be released soon", as developers said.

Read common issues here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects

From my experiences (I had same issues), the easiest way is to downgrade version.
Maybe version 16.10 will bring some other issues.